# Android resource linking failure when building signed bundle

Tags: android, gradle, build

I have a problem when I try to build a signed bundle in Android Studio: `Android resource linking failed`.
The error apparently is from `AndroidManifest.xml`, on this line:

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
   android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_nofitication"
   tools:replace="android:resource" />
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

The issue only occurs when I try to build a signed release bundle, if I build a signed debug bundle, no error message is thrown at all.